# Javascript / jquery drag and drop between two tree view listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, treeview

I was looking around for drag and drop functionality of tree listing items between two tree views (not in single tree), I found couple of them which actually does in single tree itself, however unable to find which does between two trees.

I search for it, and unable to find any free script for this, could you please point me to the right one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good example with drag'n drop between two treeviews :
http://demos.kendoui.com/treeview/dragdrop.html

From KendoUI ;)

**Edit:** another one, more complex but free : http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd

Comment: Hi, Thanks, it looks good, actually exactly what I was looking for, however its not free in commercial use, is there any similar but free to use commercially ?

Thanks

Comment: There is another plugin jstree that can do the trick with some work : http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd

Try to drag and drop the blue box into the tree ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried jstree, and so far its going good. Thanks for your help.